# Swift barChartView hide axisMinimum value

Tags: swift, charts, bar-chart

I have a question about barchartview

[image]

How to hide the axisMinimum? which I have circled on the image.

I have tried tried this:

```
barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0

barChartView.leftAxis.enabled = false
```

But it did not work, and I need the bottom line

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this question by this

```
class ChartsLeftAxisFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter {
func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
    
    if(value == -30){
        return ""
    }
    
    return "\(value)"
}
```

}